# NodeJS send response to client only after saving all object to DB

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, async-await

I have the code below, from a REST API, that inserts data in Mysql. I use Node and Express (this is, in fact, my 1st Node project, so please bear in mind I don't understand much about Node).

What I need is that response to client (browser, web application, Postman for testing or whatever access to the API) is returned **only** when the forEach loop and data insertion into DB terminates, so I get a JSON object with the list error messages, if any.

I've been hitting my head on the wall for half a day, and this is what I got so far.

```
var wait=require('wait.for');
var async = require('async');
var Promise = require('promise');
var Q = require('q');

var errmsg = [];
router.route('/subscriber').post((req, res, callback) => {
    const data = req.body; 
    
    var subscriberCollection = data;
    
    this.errmsg = [];
    
    let asyncCall =  
      (async  () => {
            let rr = await new Promise (resolve => subscriberCollection.forEach(function (value, key){      
                    
                    var phoneNumber = value.phoneNumber;
                    var msg = "";
                    if (phoneNumber == ""){
                        msg = "ERROR","missing phoneNumber for subscriber index #" + key + ";Skipping";
                        console.log(msg);
                        errmsg[key] = msg
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    var sql = "call insertSubscriber(?)";           
                    console.log("INFO",`Inserting subscriber ${phoneNumber} index ${key}`);
                        
                        connection.query(sql,[ phoneNumber ] ,function (err, data) {            
                            if (err){ 
                                var msg = err.errno + " - " + err.sqlMessage;
                                console.log("ERROR" , msg);
                                errmsg[key] = msg;
                            }
                        });
                        
                }) //end forEach
            ); //end Promise    
    })();
    
    asyncCall.then(console.log("ENDING!!") ); // THIS IS NOT WORKING

});
```

On the console, I get this:

```
INFO Inserting 916311145 for index 0
INFO Inserting 916311146 for index 1
ENDING!!
ERROR 1062 - Duplicate entry '916311145' for key 'phoneNumber_UNIQUE'
ERROR 1062 - Duplicate entry '916311146' for key 'phoneNumber_UNIQUE'
```

but what I need it to be is:

```
INFO Inserting 916311145 for index 0
INFO Inserting 916311146 for index 1
ERROR 1062 - Duplicate entry '916311145' for key 'phoneNumber_UNIQUE'
ERROR 1062 - Duplicate entry '916311146' for key 'phoneNumber_UNIQUE'
ENDING!!
```

Also, when all subscriber objects are saved on DB, I need to return a response to client, something like:

```
[{"key 0" : "ok"},{"key 1" : "ok"}, {"key 3": "ERROR 1062 - Duplicate entry '916311145' for key 'phoneNumber_UNIQUE'"}...]
```

and again, the response should only appear when all processing has finished.
How can I get this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm try this:

```
var wait = require('wait.for');
var async = require('async');
var Promise = require('promise');
var Q = require('q');

router.route('/subscriber').post(async (req, res, callback) => {
    const data = req.body;

    var subscriberCollection = data;

    const response = await Promise.all(
        subscriberCollection.map(function (value, key) {
            var phoneNumber = value.phoneNumber;
            var msg = '';
            const obj = {};

            if (phoneNumber == '') {
                msg = 'ERROR missing phoneNumber for subscriber index #' + key + ';Skipping';
                console.log(msg);
                obj[key] = msg;
                Promise.resolve(obj);
                return;
            }

            var sql = 'call insertSubscriber(?)';
            console.log('INFO', `Inserting subscriber ${phoneNumber} index ${key}`);
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                connection.query(sql, [phoneNumber], function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        var msg = 'ERROR' + err.errno + ' - ' + err.sqlMessage;
                        console.log(msg);
                        obj[key] = msg;
                        resolve(obj);
                        return;
                    }
                    obj[key] = 'ok';
                    resolve(obj);
                });
            });
        }) //end forEach
    ); //end Promise

    console.log('ENDING!!');
    res.send(response);
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I will have to study what your solution does, there are many functions I have no clue what they do (like Promise.all and <collection>.map) . Thanks for your help!

Comment: @scharrua Happy to help! I do recommend as a beginner learn these two concepts: promises & callbacks and you'll be on your merry way (both exist in the code I wrote)!